# MS SQL - Delete query taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query script:

```
declare @tblSectionsList table
(
    SectionID int,
    SectionCode varchar(255)
)
--assume @tblSectionsList has 50 sections- rows

DELETE 
    td
from 
    [dbo].[InventoryDocumentDetails] td
    inner join [dbo].InventoryDocuments th 
          on th.Id = td.InventoryDocumentDetail_InventoryDocument
    inner join @tblSectionsList ts 
          on ts.SectionID = th.InventoryDocument_Section
```

This script contains three tables, where `@tblSectionsList` is a temporary table, it may contains 50 records. Then I am using this table in the join condition with the `InventoryDocuments` table, then further joined to the `InventoryDocumentDetails` table. All joins are based on INT foreign-keys.

On the week-end I put this query on server and it is still running even after 2 days,4 hours... Can any body tell me if I am doing something wrong. Or is there any idea to improve its performance? Even I don't know how much more time it will take to give me the result.

Before this I also tried to create an index on the `InventoryDocumentDetails` table with following script:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_InventoryDocumentDetails_InventoryDocument
    ON dbo.InventoryDocumentDetails (InventoryDocumentDetail_InventoryDocument);
```

But this script also take more than one day and did not finish so I cancelled this query.

Additional info:

- I am using MS SQL 2008 R2.
- InventoryDocuments table contains 2108137 rows, has primary key 'Id'.
- InventoryDocumentDetails table contains 25055158 rows, has primary key 'Id'.
- Both tables have primary keys defined.
- CUP - Intel Xeon - with 32 GB RAM
- No indexes are defined, because now when I am going to create a new index, that query also get suspended.

Query Execution Plan (1):
[image]

2nd Part:
[image]

The following query give one row for this and showing status='suspended', and wait_type='LCK_M_IX'

```
SELECT r.session_id as spid, r.[status], r.command, t.[text], OBJECT_NAME(t.objectid, t.[dbid]) as object, r.logical_reads, r.blocking_session_id as blocked, r.wait_type, s.host_name, s.host_process_id, s.program_name, r.start_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON s.session_id = r.session_id OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.[sql_handle]) AS t
WHERE r.session_id <> @@SPID AND r.session_id > 50
```

Comment: You should include the query plan to your question. Also, did you check that there is no blocking causing the delete to wait?

Comment: The next dude posting RAM - but not talking about database size, query plan and DISC SUBSYSTEMS. The server may well run on totally inappropriate slow hard discs. Query plan, please. And disc layout.

Comment: It successfully deletes other queries, like 10 million rows from another table in 1 minute. Database size is approx 15 GB.

Comment: I usually use a simple query like this to check what's going & blocking http://pastebin.com/F4eQxGTx You could also use Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive

Comment: I don't think you can attach the actual .sqlplan here, probably it's best to attach a picture of it here and maybe upload it somewhere if someone wants to look it more closely.

Comment: execution plan is added in question

Comment: @MIdrees What wait types are the individual tasks belonging to that session showing in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`?

Comment: Quick note: *"`@tblSectionsList` is a temporary table"* is not true. `@tblSectionsList` is a `TABLE` variable and there's quite some differences between `TABLE` variables and temporary tables.

Comment: Please include in your question `TABLE` definitions (including `INDEX`/`PRIMARY KEY`) for all tables involved in the query.

Comment: You didn't say what primary keys exist and fields they include. A primary key is a special kind of index and is relevant to your question.

Comment: There are only two tables, each have identity column Id as primary key.

Comment: I'm seeing clustered index scan on `InventoryDocumentDetailExtensions`... What's that doing there?

Comment: Yes that is similar table like InventoryDocumentDetails, have one-to-one relation one primary key. Both tables has PK='Id'. But in this delete query, I am not touching that table. Do you think it is taking role in this deleet script.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key with cascading delete?

Comment: You have `TRIGGER`s on `InventoryDocumentDetails`, or cascading DELETE foreign keys... Really I can't be bothered to look at this any further without you providing **all** relevant details to this question. TABLE definitions, all constraints, indexes, primary keys, the works.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6rY3gSKp
http://pastebin.com/qujaNYAY
Table Definitions for InventoryDocumentDetails and InventoryDocumentDetailExtensions. Yes unfortunately there is foreign-key cascade delete in extensions table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you change the `Inner Join` to `EXISTS`

```
DELETE td
FROM   [dbo].[InventoryDocumentDetails] td
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   [dbo].InventoryDocuments th
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM   @tblSectionsList ts
                              WHERE  ts.SectionID = th.InventoryDocument_Section)
                      AND th.Id = td.InventoryDocumentDetail_InventoryDocument)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @VR46, it works. query completed in just 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes can be more efficient time-wise to truncate a table and re-import the records you want to keep. A delete operation on a large tables is incredibly slow compared to an insert. Of course this is only an option if you can take your table offline. Also, only do this if your logging is set to simple.

1. Drop triggers table A.
2. Bulk copy table A to B.
3. Truncate table A
4. Enable Identity Insert.
5. Insert Into A From B Where A.ID Not in ID's to delete.
6. Disable Identity Insert.
7. Rebuild indexes.
8. Enable triggers

Comment: Thanks @Irb for providing another trick. Below (user=VR46) answer has done the job, but this is also workable suggestion in hard-times.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the below. It might give you some idea at least.

```
     DELETE FROM [DBO].[INVENTORYDOCUMENTDETAILS] WHERE INVENTORYDOCUMENTDETAILS_PK IN (
     (SELECT INVENTORYDOCUMENTDETAILS_PK FROM
     [DBO].[INVENTORYDOCUMENTDETAILS] TD
     INNER JOIN [DBO].INVENTORYDOCUMENTS TH ON TH.ID = TD.INVENTORYDOCUMENTDETAIL_INVENTORYDOCUMENT
     INNER JOIN @TBLSECTIONSLIST TS ON TS.SECTIONID = TH.INVENTORYDOCUMENT_SECTION
      )
```